# Is it possible to animate a img on hover of a button?

Tags: html, css

Im using replete to create a button that on hover it will make the question mark sort of move to the side of where the padding is created but its not working I've tried using `.button:hover + img {animation: left 2s;}` but that didn't work I tried using `.button:hover + img { position: absolute; left: 47%;}` but that hasn't helped I tried using a div but that hasn't helped.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2&family=Kablammo&family=Rubik+80s+Fade&family=Space+Mono&family=VT323&display=swap');

@keyframes left {
  from {left: 55%;}
  to {left: 57%;}
}

.button:hover + img {
  animation: left 2sl
}

.button {
  background-color: #27282c;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

img {
   position: absolute;
    top: 69%;
    left: 55%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Question_mark_%28black%29.svg/800px-Question_mark_%28black%29.svg.png">

<hint><button class="button" onclick="clicked()">Click me</button></hint>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that `button + img` ignores the `hint` element. If you assign the `:hover` pseudo attribute to the `hint`, like `hint:hover + img{}` ~ oh and you need to move the img to after the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the `img` element to after the button (or the hint actually) and modify the `:hover` to be triggered by the `hint` element I think you get the effect you were after

```js
const clicked=(e)=>console.log('ok')
```

```css
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2&family=Kablammo&family=Rubik+80s+Fade&family=Space+Mono&family=VT323&display=swap');

@keyframes left {
  from {
    left: 55%;
  }
  to {
    left: 57%;
  }
}
/* 
  assign the :hover attribute to the hint as the hint has the img as
  it will be the hint that has a following element of `img`
  There is no means in css to find preceeding or parent elements
  so the + selector finds the next adjacent element rather than a previous
  element.
*/
hint:hover + img {
  animation:left 250ms forwards linear;
}




.button {
  background-color: #27282c;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

img {
  position:absolute;
  left:55%;
  top: 69%;
  
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out all;
}
```

```html
<hint>
  <button class="button" onclick="clicked()">Click me</button>
</hint>

<img
   width='5rem' 
   height='5rem' 
   alt='Question everything' 
   title='Question everything'
  src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Question_mark_%28black%29.svg/800px-Question_mark_%28black%29.svg.png" />
```